# Control Point for Quadratic Bezier Curves

Tags: android

I am new to Android APIs and I am working on an application where I have a curveTool object which is supposed to first draw a line and when you touch the screen a second time basically create a control point and curve the previously drawn line based on the control point.
so basically I have:

```
public void touchStart(MotionEvent event) {
    points = new ArrayList<PointF>();
    points.add(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY()));
}
```

which creates the starting points and I have:

```
public void touchEnd(MotionEvent event) {
    points.add(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY()));
}
```

where I create the end points of the line, but I am not sure how I will have to implement the control point using `quadTo()` method and make the line curve based on it.
there is also a third method:

```
public void touchMove(MotionEvent event) {
    points.add(new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY()));
}
```

where I keep adding points.

And finally I draw using the following method:

```
public void drawPreview(Canvas canvas) {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

I know that there is a lot of code missing, but I am not sure how to implement it.  I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you asking how to draw quadratic curves on an Android device? Are you asking for more than links to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html (calling out drawPath) and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html (calling out quadTo)?

Comment: I basically don't know how to create a control point and have it curve my line when dragging it

Comment: So you're asking how to architect your application to track the user's touch and link it to a point and make that point behave as a control point on a curve that you also need to maintain endpoints for, all while drawing the curve?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes, this is exactly what I am planning to accomplish. I have however no idea how to do that using quadTo!

Comment: Your statements don't make sense. I'm trying to ask if your confusion is over using quadTo or in designing an application that can track point positions. Then you answer that you are having problem designing your application (not using quadTo), but then you also say you are having problems using quadTo. Which is it? Your question is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use quadTo, you must create a Path object, call quadTo on the Path, then draw the path onto a canvas.